# VSCode Notebook extension is not recognizing my python environments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

For about two weeks I can't get the extension to work.
I can see all my environments in the Interperter selector menu but not in the kernel picker. I used to run my conda environments with no problems now I cant find ANY environment or python installation at all

The error I get is:

```
12:43:26.840 [error] Failed to install Python Extension via Kernel Picker command
12:43:26.841 [warn] DataScience Error [Error: Failed to install the Python Extension.
    at Vy.installPythonExtensionViaKernelPicker (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.11.1003402403-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:265:9578)
    at async d.h (~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:141:140086)]
```

It looks like it thinks I don't have python installed.

I'm running Win 11

- VSC 1.85.1
- Jupyter ext: v2023.11.1003402403
- Python ext: v2023.22.1

I have reinstalled VSC and Jupyter/Python extensions, switched to older versions, upgraded it all again but nothing seem to work. My path is correct and works with powershell and I can run normal python scripts with my environments. Deleting ALL VS cash folders seem to work but the problem came back at every restart.

Comment: Have you tried to use another python kernel.